# XPath and android

Tags: java, android, xpath

On my android program I have a XML file based on `res/xml/myFile.xml` This file have the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <ip>192.168.1.189</ip> 
    <port>2000</port>
</configuration>
```

I tried to get value from `port` node with the following code :

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.myFile);
InputSource inSrc = new InputSource(is);
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlFile = builder.parse(inSrc);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/configuration/port");
Node node = (Node)expr.evaluate(xmlFile, XPathConstants.NODE);
String port = node.getNodeValue();
```

With this code **node** is equal to NULL. Someone got an idea, why i get a NULL value on **node** and how i can do to get value from **ip** and **port** node ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that expr is correct? As in, you might want to test that expr isn't null to eliminate a possible source of the error.

Comment: And are you sure that xmlFile is proper? You might try passing inSrc instead of xmlFile, based on the documentation it looks like inSrc should work just as well (?) as xmlFile. If inSrc works, then the problem is somewhere with your xmlFile chain.

Comment: What do you mean for expr is correct ? By the way, it is not equal to NULL. My XML file can be run without issue into a browser. If I passing inSrc instead of xmlFile, a SAXParseException : *Unexpected end of docuement* is thrown